# Different Instance Types for different versions

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to use F2 for test versions and F4 for main version of appengine (java) application?

We have various teams and they work differently but they do not need F4. They are happy with F1 or even F2. But the main core version needs F4.

Comment: IF you use modules, you can define an hardware class for each module
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Instance_scaling_and_class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [App Engine Modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/). We use them to assign different instance types for different parts of our app (even if the parts share a common code-base). For example:

- `default` - serves front end module. F4 with automatic scaling with 1 resident instance.
- `api` - serves REST api calls. B4 with basic scaling.
- `api-simple` - serves simple api calls with lower latency. F2 with automatic scaling with 1 resident instance.

Comment: Thanks. How do we ensure that session between various modules? Eg: apia and api-simple. If a user logins, how can share this info amongst various other modules in Java.

Comment: @cloudpre As long as all of the modules are on the same domain, there shouldn't be problems with session managing. In my case the entire session is encrypted inside the cookie itself. I believe that the same could work for you. In addition, the Memcache and the Datastore are shared between modules.

Comment: We use wildcard subdomaining for our customers but it seems possible. Thanks for the suggestion to look in this direction. Any reason on why you had one for api and api-simple and not together? Is this to save costs or to increase performance? Why backend versus frontend?

Comment: @cloudpre Yes it is mainly to save costs. We have many "lightweight" api calls and fewer "heavy" api calls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think modules will solve your problem, since you are talking about the same application but different versions of it (With modules you can't assign different hardware to different versions).

GAE doesn't currently support assigning different hardware for different versions of your app. At my company we had to create different applications in order to benefit from different hardware and resident instances (which are not supported by non-default versions of your app).

So we ended up having:

- app
- app-staging
- app-v2

etc.

This is horrible but so far is the only solution available (at least that I'm aware of).